# CSS to mimic an iOS/Android table row

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a row that spans the width of my device that the user can tap to take then to a specified link.

I've created an image that is the 'disclosure indicator' (chevron) found on table rows in iOS. I just can't figure out how I can set my multi-line text to the left of the chevron, and keep the chevron to the right of the text and centered. (see image).

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` to vertically align the chevron.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/8psb8naq/)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px;
}
div:after {
  content: '›';
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #444;
  right: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```